# Google and Facebook sign in redirection issue after kill the app in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am logging in through google or Facebook and then logging out from app. After that if I kill the application and again try to log in through any of Facebook or Google it is not redirecting me to application. After I click login, this will take me to the browser and when I click on allow or ok button in browser the it is not coming to my app and opening google.com or Facebook page.

Please help me on this issue. I am not able to go further.

Comment: If I kill the app after sign in then also I am not able to login again after logout. Please suggest me anything. Previously it was working fine. I did not do anything in code. Now it behaving like this.

Comment: I cant share the code as per company's policy, hope u'll understand. But yes its working in my sample project. It suddenly started behaving like this in my main project. Previously everything was working fine. I did not change any thing related to this. dont know why this ia happening now